# FormView is not showing validation errors

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

My model.py looks:

```
class VehicleInquiry(TimeStampedModel):
    inquiry_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("inquiry status"), choices=INQUIRY_STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(_("IP"), blank=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(_("full name"), max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(_("address"), max_length=200)
    phone_code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("phone code")
    )
    phone = models.CharField(_("phone"), max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email"))

is_subscribed = models.BooleanField(_("subscribed"), default=True)
vehicle = models.ForeignKey(VehicleStock, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                        related_name="inquiries", verbose_name=_("vehicle")
)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                        related_name="inquiries", verbose_name=_("country")
)
arrival_port = models.ForeignKey(CountryPorts, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                        related_name="inquiries", verbose_name=_("arrival port")
)

current_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('current price'), null=True, blank=True)
inspection = models.BooleanField(_("pre-export inspection"), default=False)
insurance = models.BooleanField(_("insurance"), default=True)
total = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('total price'), null=True, blank=True)
```

my form.py:

```
class VehicleInquiryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label=_("Country"),
        choices=[('','Arrival Country')]+[(country.id, country.name) for country in Country.objects.all().filter(visible=True).order_by('name')],
        required=True,
    )
    phone_code = ChoiceFieldWithTitles(
        label=_("Country dialing code"),
        choices=[('','Dailing Code', 'Dailing Code')]+[(country.id, '{} (+{})'.format(country.name, country.phone_code), '+{}'.format(country.phone_code)) for country in Country.objects.all().filter(visible=True).order_by('name')],
        required=True,
    )
    arrival_port = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label=False,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect
    )    

    phone = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Phone"),
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        validators=[phone_number_validator]
        )

    full_name = StrippedCharField(
        label=_("Full name"),
        max_length=30,
        required=True,
        validators=[full_name_validator]
        )

    address = StrippedCharField(
        label=_("Address"),
        max_length=200,
        required=True
        )        

    class Meta:
        model = VehicleInquiry
        exclude = ('inquiry_status', 'vehicle', 'current_price', 'total')    


    def clean_country2(self):
        country_id = self.cleaned_data['country2']
        try:
            country = Country.objects.get(id=country_id)
        except Country.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please select the country'))
        return country_id

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(VehicleInquiryForm, self).clean()
        dialing_code = cleaned_data['phone_code']
        try:
            dialing_country = Country.objects.get(id=dialing_code)
        except Country.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please select the phone code'))
        return self.cleaned_data

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dialing_code = kwargs.pop('phone_code', None)
        super(VehicleInquiryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['is_subscribed'].label = _("Keep me updated with news, specials offers and more.")
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.template_pack = "bootstrap3"
        self.helper.form_method = "post"
        self.helper.form_id = "vehicle-shipping-form"
        self.helper.form_show_errors = True
        self.initial['insurance'] = True
        self.fields['phone_code'].initial = dialing_code
        self.helper.add_input(
            Submit('inquiry', _('Inquiry'), css_class='btn btn-default',)
        )
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
            _("1. Choose Your Final Destination"),
            Div(
                Field('country2', css_class="order-select-country"),
            ),
-- other fields --
)
```

view.py

```
class VehicleStockDetailView(FormView):
    template_name = "site/product/vehicle-detail.html"
    template_name_done = "site/contact/contact-us-done.html"
    template_name_done_email = "site/contact/emails/contact-us-done.html"
    form_class = VehicleInquiryForm
    model = VehicleStock

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        vehicle = get_object_or_404(VehicleStock, slug=slug)
        similar_vehicles = VehicleStock.objects.get_public_available().filter(model__id=vehicle.model.id).exclude(slug=slug)[:6]
        page_title = vehicle.model

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'page_title': page_title, 'similar_products': similar_vehicles, 'stock_product': vehicle, 'shipping_form': form})

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        vehicle = get_object_or_404(VehicleStock, slug=slug)
        similar_vehicles = VehicleStock.objects.get_public_available().filter(model__id=vehicle.model.id).exclude(slug=slug)[:6]
        page_title = vehicle.model
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(self.request, self.template_name_done, {'full_name': request.POST['full_name'], 'email': request.POST['email']})

        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'page_title': page_title, 'similar_products': similar_vehicles, 'stock_product': vehicle, 'shipping_form': form})
```

url.py

```
url(r'^vehicle/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', VehicleStockDetailView.as_view(), name='vehicle-detail'),
```

Now, when I fill the form and send inquiry it is not showing any error but showing again the form with entered field values except phone_code (it is showing default value). No errors showing, but the form is not validated. I tried different ways with TemplateView and with FormView. But no success.Deadly need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed the POSTed data to the form anywhere.

This is one of the reasons why you should not be overriding the `get` and `post` methods. The point of the various class-based views is that they do almost all of this for you. You should be inheriting from CreateView, so that the form is saved when it is valid, and the extra logic you have added should be in `get_context_data` - as you can see, this avoids having to include the same code twice.

```
class VehicleStockDetailView(CreateView):
    template_name = "site/product/vehicle-detail.html"
    template_name_done = "site/contact/contact-us-done.html"
    template_name_done_email = "site/contact/emails/contact-us-done.html"
    form_class = VehicleInquiryForm
    model = VehicleStock

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(VehicleStockDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['vehicle'] = get_object_or_404(VehicleStock, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context['similar_vehicles'] = VehicleStock.objects.get_public_available().filter(model__id=vehicle.model.id).exclude(slug=slug)[:6]
        context['page_title'] = vehicle.model

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = form.save()
        return render(self.request, self.template_name_done, {'full_name': self.request.POST['full_name'], 'email': self.request.POST['email']})
```

Note also that you really should never directly render a template on success; you should always redirect. Again, the form view takes care of this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your promp answer. I cannot check it immediately, because I used slug in url using reverse. I cannot get it from kwargs. Can I do it using FormView. Here it says, I can use get and post of FormView https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.7/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

Comment: You should show your urls.py. The only reason why you wouldn't be able to get it from kwargs is if you defined it as a positional argument, in which case it should be in `self.args[0]`.

Comment: url(r'^vehicle/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', VehicleStockDetailView.as_view(), name='vehicle-detail'),

Comment: So it should definitely be in `self.kwargs`.

Comment: it is there. I solved it, now it throws VariableDoesNotExist error, showing the link to the form in template {% crispy shipping_form %}

Comment: Because the form is just called `form`, not `shipping_form`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132813/discussion-between-alex-sh-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: I changed. It runs as before, shows entered values, but not validating. No validation errors. I really stuck.